# Searching asp.net Code

Tags: asp.net, search, refactoring

I want to search my asp.net pages and user controls to see which master page and base class they use. I mention search because we are re-factoring a large project and we need to track progress on the code conversion. I know I can pull this information individually but I need a automated and repeatable procedure.

Answer (score 0):

A general purpose tool for searching .Net Applications ASP.Net or otherwise is **.Net Reflector** you can walk the dependencies and even transform from C# to VB or the other way around.  I like to use the search abilities to find Classes or Error Strings when I am debugging issues.  You can also use the Analyze option to see all the places in the code that call a specific method.  http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/.  I hope this helps.